# Select all records in table B with same PK and different property values as in table A

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, filtering

I have two tables TA and TB. Both use the same PK (TB is a shadow table of TA). I need to identify all records from TA that are also in TB, but have one or more property values changed.

Sample code:

```cs
public class MyData 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PK { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public int Value1 { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Value2 { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

What I need is something like find all records R from TA in TB where `R(TA).PK == R(TB).PK && (R(TA).Value1 != R(TB).Value1 || R(TA).Value1 != R(TB).Value1)`

However, I have no bloody clue how to write that down, neither as sql nor as Linq statement. I tried a lot of variants, but none was syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = ctx.TA.Where(a => ctx.TB.Any(b => a.PK == b.PK && 
  (a.Value1 != b.Value1 || a.Value2 != b.Value2)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Easier than I thought. I thought Any() would only return a bool value, so I didn't look into it.

Comment: Easier but not effective.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff, yes it returns a boolean and here that is what we are after (that would translate to EXISTS in SQL).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, what makes it ineffective?

Comment: Generated SQL and execution plan.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, this generates one with EXISTS and yours with a JOIN. I am still at a lost why this one is ineffective.

Comment: Db Engine optimizer MAY predict what is needed but not always. JOIN is very fast operation instead of EXISTS.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, you are assuming PK is primary key I think. In that case, both are effective enough. If it is not, then did you ever try benchmarking them (and possibly on different databases)? And mind you EXISTS generate a better execution plan.

Comment: Just tested on SQL Server - execution plan is the same. Also tested on less smart DB Engine - `MySql`, EXISTS execution plan is worse.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, mysql is not my thing. postgreSQL test would be better. Let's say you are right. Yours should be 100 milliseconds faster on a million rows.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, on postgreSQL (on a more smart db engin) exists worked better even on windows but difference is negligible IMHO - 20 ms on 1 million rows (692 vs 672 ms - repeated runs similar)

Comment: PostgreSQL the same execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query =
    from ta in context.TableA
    join tb in context.TableB on ta.PK equals tb.PK
    where ta.Value1 != tb.Value1 || ta.Value2 != tb.Value2
    select ta;
```